# CSS - linear gradient not working in any browser

Tags: css, reactjs, webkit

I've a `class` as:

```
.breadcrumb_area {
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(180deg, #5e2ced 0%, #a485fd 100%);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(180deg, #5e2ced 0%, #a485fd 100%);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(180deg, #5e2ced 0%, #a485fd 100%);
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 235px 0px 125px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Now, I am using predefined html css template. This class works fine in template pages. But the same class when I use in `react` page, it's not working.

In chrome developer tools the line `background-image` has been strike through.

```
<section className="breadcrumb_area">
        <img className="breadcrumb_shap" src={`${banner_bg}`} alt="" />
        <div className="container">
            <div className="breadcrumb_content text-center">
                <h1 className="f_p f_700 f_size_50 w_color l_height50 mb_20">Services</h1>
                <p className="f_300 w_color f_size_16 l_height26">
                  Why I say old chap that is spiffing off his nut arse pear shaped plastered<br/> 
                  Jeffrey bodge barney some dodgy.!!
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

The same thing works [here as well](https://jsfiddle.net/akcu4htz/1/)

**How do I use linear-gradient for all the browsers ?**

Comment: remove everything and simply use `background-image:linear-gradient(180deg, #5e2ced 0%, #a485fd 100%);`

Comment: @TemaniAfif super that works. no more vendor prefix ? is it W3C specification now ?

Comment: since too long now .. but in all the cases you should always use the non-vendor version and not ONLY the vendor version. To be sure it will be fine use the prefixes then use the non-prefixed one, like that you are sure it will work

Comment: @TemaniAfif I've total 165 such lines of code in css. what do you prefer ?

Comment: for gradient I would use only the non prefixed one

Answer (score 0):

```css
.breadcrumb_area {
  background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, #5e2ced 0%, #a485fd 100%);
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 235px 0px 125px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

and for build i added [autoprefixer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/autoprefixer) in babel or webpack config

its works for me